# How do I filter emails from mailing lists that have no "to:" entry?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I have a small 5 man team and we use Google for our email. All of the mail goes to **mail@example.com** and we filter it to our personal emails from there. So if someone sends mail to **johndoe@example.com** it gets caught by the "to:" filter and passed on.

I keep getting 'indirect' emails, usually from mailing lists that people signed up for, that the filter can't catch.

**For Example:**

```
from:    gov-list <gov-list@domain.com>  
to:    
cc:      gov-list <gov-list@domain.com>  
date:    Wed, Apr 22, 2015 at 11:04 AM  
subject: email list stuff
```

1. Why can't I see who this is being sent to?
2. How can I properly filter these to the right people?

Comment: TO is blank means that mail is not for you any of 5 , right? That is junk mail?

Answer (score 1):

You probably can't see who it's being sent to because the sender didn't put a value in the to: field. This is fairly common for mailing lists and such and is a courtesy; I know I get annoyed when my email address is exposed in a message sent to hundreds of people.

If you open up the message menu and choose "Show Original", you'll get a view of the raw email, including the headers. The "delivered-to:" heading there will let you know who the ultimate recipient was.

To filter these messages, you'll want to use the `deliveredto:` operator. In your filter, in the "Has the words" field, put

```
deliveredto:username@example.com
```

(Obviously, replace the email address with the email address you're filtering for.)